# Any way to get a specific entry by key in a Java hashmap(having inserted multiple values)?

Tags: java, class, object, hashmap, var

I have a Java hashmap, to which multiple variables were added(ex.):

```
class client {
    public static int clientIdentifier;
    public static String clientName;
    public static String clientFamilyname;
    public static String clientBirthdate;
}
```

Inside the main method:

```
client newclient = new client();
HashMap<Integer, String> clients = new HashMap<>();

clients.put(newclient.clientIdentifier,  
newclient.clientName + 
newclient.clientFamilyname +
 newclient.clientBirthdate
```

Where new client.clientIdentifier is the key and newClient.clientName/Familyname/Birthdate are already defined. They belong to an object newclient, it belonging to the class client

**Is there any way to get only the value clientName from that hashmap, to compare later?**

Looking for something like:
`String requiredName = clients.get(scannedID, newclient.clientName);`

(I know that it is totally wrong, but just to have an idea)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make all the fields in `Client` non-static first! You'd want each instance of `Client` to have a different ID, name, and birthday, right?

Instead of using a `HashMap<Integer, String>`, use a `HashMap<Integer, Client>`:

```
Client newclient = new Client();
HashMap<Integer, Client> clients = new HashMap<>();

clients.put(newclient.clientIdentifier, newclient);
```

Now you can just do:

```
String requiredName = clients.get(scannedID).clientName;
```

But really though, the fields in the class `Client` should all be private and should be accessed via [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors). You also should not be able to reset the client's `clientIdentifier` as that is the map's key.

`Client` should look like this:

```
class Client {
    private int clientIdentifier;
    private String clientName;
    private String clientFamilyname;
    private String clientBirthdate;

    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }

    public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public String getClientFamilyname() {
        return clientFamilyname;
    }

    public void setClientFamilyname(String clientFamilyname) {
        this.clientFamilyname = clientFamilyname;
    }

    public String getClientBirthdate() {
        return clientBirthdate;
    }

    public void setClientBirthdate(String clientBirthdate) {
        this.clientBirthdate = clientBirthdate;
    }

    public int getClientIdentifier() {
        return clientIdentifier;
    }

    public Client(int clientIdentifier, String clientName, String clientFamilyname, String clientBirthdate) {
        this.clientIdentifier = clientIdentifier;
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.clientFamilyname = clientFamilyname;
        this.clientBirthdate = clientBirthdate;
    }
}
```

Your hash map code will now look like:

```
Client newclient = new Client();
HashMap<Integer, Client> clients = new HashMap<>();

clients.put(newclient.getClientIdentifier(), newclient);

String requiredName = clients.get(scannedID).getClientName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the value in the hashmap something like this:

```
map.put(clientID,name+"+"+familyname+"+"+bithdate);
```

This way when I get the value from Map using the key, I would get a string like John+Wood+1994.
Now I can easily get the name by using substring.
Does this help ?